# “MySQL support not included in PHP”

Tags: drupal, php, civicrm.settings.php

I have drupal running perfectly; with mysql support. But CiviCRM still giving me this error - “MySQL support not included in PHP.”

My PHP version is 5.6.31, as indicated in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Which civi version are you trying to install?

Comment: Civi version is 4.7.22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your drupal may be using a different mysql driver. CiviCRM recently migrated to requiring mysqli. See https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/psa-please-verify-php-extension-mysqli for more details.

Comment: In which version of civi they have migrated to mysqli?

Comment: I recompiled php with --with-mysqli and it is working now.